# How to load JSON from URL and display by using plain javascript on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, json, url

I'm trying to get JSON data from the specific URL and display it on the HTML page to check whether it works or not. I have no idea about what is wrong and I should fix on my code.

```
<script>
        var jsonDoc="";
        function loadJSON(url){
            //alert(url);
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.open('GET', url, false);
            request.responseType = 'json';
            request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                    jsonDoc = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                }else{
                    jsonDoc = null;
                }

                request.send();

            };
        }
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = jsonDoc;
</script>

<body>
    <h1>Enter URL for Highest-grossing films List JSON File</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="url" value=""><br>
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Query" onclick="loadJSON(document.getElementById('url').value)">
    </form>

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of errors preventing your code from doing what you want it to do.

1. You are trying to access the element that has the `content` id
   before the element is loaded on the page. Think of it like this.
   Your `script` and `body` elements are organized in such a way that
   your `script` will load and execute first before the `body` element
   and its children are loaded.

   The culprit is this line:
   `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = jsonDoc`.

   It belongs in the `onreadystatechange` function because you only
   want to update `content` when you have received the data from the
   API.

   If you move that line to the `onreadystatechange` function, you now
   have access to the data you retrieved from the API and do not need
   the `jsonDoc` global variable.
2. The `request.responseType = 'json'` code raises this descriptive
   error.

   `InvalidAccessError: synchronous XMLHttpRequests do not support
   timeout and responseType.`

   Delete that line of code because it is attempting an operation that is not
   allowed.
3. You are never sending a request because `request.send()` is inside
   the code that handles the API's response. It should be outside that function.
4. In the `onreadystatechange` function, you will also want to
   `JSON.stringify` the data after using `JSON.parse` to make it into
   the string you want to display.

After fixing all of that, your JavaScript should look similar to this.

```
<script>
  function loadJSON(url) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', url, false);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
      }
    };
    request.send();
  }
</script>
```

A more modern JavaScript practice is to use the `fetch` API. It makes fetching data from APIs a lot easier. Here is the equivalent of the code above, using the `fetch` API.

```
<script>
  function loadJSON(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(function(res) { return res.json(); })
      .then(function(data) {
         document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
      });
  }
</script>
```

You can read more about [using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) on MDN.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections! It works perfectly the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the DOM after response is received.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // here
};
```

Also move `request.send();` outside of `request.onreadystatechange` callback:

```
    var jsonDoc="";
    function loadJSON(url){
        //alert(url);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', url, false);
        request.responseType = 'json';
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                jsonDoc = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = jsonDoc;
            }else{
                jsonDoc = null;
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be off base here, but the main thing I thought was wrong in your approach was that the input text field did not have a 'name' field.  I made some changes in your code so that I could track down a way to get the value of that name field out to look at its value.  This may not be what you wanted, but it gives a way to find your parameters and you can then do with them as you wish.  Here is the modified code with a couple of simple javascript functions to assist:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getURLParameters(paramName)
{
    var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();
    alert('sURL = ' + sURL);
    if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0)
    {
        var arrParams = sURL.split("?");
        var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&");
        var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
        var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);

        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<arrURLParams.length; i++)
        {
            var sParam =  arrURLParams[i].split("=");
            arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];
            if (sParam[1] != "")
                arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
            else
                arrParamValues[i] = "No Value";
        }

        for (i=0; i<arrURLParams.length; i++)
        {
            if (arrParamNames[i] == paramName)
            {
                alert("Parameter:" + arrParamValues[i]);
                return arrParamValues[i];
            }
        }
        return "No Parameters Found";
    }
}
 function printDiv(divName) {
     alert('In printDiv with divName '+divName);
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     var replyStr = "Post parameters for 'dest':\r\n" + getURLParameters('dest'); // "1234";
     alert(replyStr);
     document.write(replyStr);
//     document.body.innerHTML = replyStr;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enter URL </h1>
    <form >
        <input type="text"  name="dest" value=""/><br/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Query" onClick="return(printDiv('printableArea'))"/>
    </form>

    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="printableArea">
      <h1>Print me</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I was going to put the response back into the printableAres innerHTML, but got it to write out and stopped there.  Main changes were to add a name 'dest' to the textfield that received the URL, and process the form data using getURLParams for the field value for 'dest'.  You can probably work out what you wanted to do from here.  Hope this helps.